# Como criar múltiplos lambdas que chamam uma mesma função com diferentes parâmetros?

Tags: python, expressões-lambda

Suponha que eu queira criar uma aplicação que consiste em vários botões que chamam uma mesma função, no entanto, passando diferentes argumentos (números de 1 à N).

Se eu tivesse que criar 10 botões desses, eu escreveria 10 linhas de código. Se eu tivesse que criar 50 botões desses, eu escreveria 50 linhas de código. Notem que isso não parece muito prático.

Uma solução que um iniciante poderia pensar é usar o `for...range` para automatizar esse processo, dessa forma:

```
for i in range(100):
    button = Button(root, command = lambda: function(i))
    button.pack()
```

O problema é que isso não daria certo, porque o Python não "salva" o valor da variável dentro do `lambda` a cada iteração. As variáveis usadas dentro do `lambda` são tratadas como "globais" quanto à sua leitura. Isto é, a referência da variável dentro do `lambda` é a mesma da variável fora dela.

```
def func(x): print(x)

var = 10

# Inicialmente pensamos que sempre que chamarmos a função anônima, ele vai imprimir 10
f = lambda: func(var) 
f() # Opa! Imprimiu o valor 10 como esperado.

# E se mudarmos o valor da variável?
var = 20
f() # Puts... ele imprime o valor 20. Ou seja, o valor da variável não é salvo no lambda.
```

Sendo assim, existe alguma forma de automatizar esse processo em Python? Em outras palavras, é possível criar dinamicamente vários `lambda` que chamam uma mesma função, porém com diferentes argumentos?

Comment: Li várias vezes sua pergunta, mas honestamente não consegui entender; por que o `for...range` não funcionaria? O que é essa variável que você precisa "salvar"?

Comment: @Rfroes87 Execute o código por si mesmo. Você vai ver que no fim da execução, para qualquer botão que eu tente apertar, ele vai chamar a função passando o argumento `99`. Isso porque o valor `99` é o último valor atribuído a variável no laço de repetição.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para isso ficar claro para você e para os demais.

Comment: A mim pareceu um problema XY. O parâmetro deveria ser propriedade do botão e não da lambda ou do que quer que fosse. No Java Swing dá pra instanciar um `JButton` e setar nele um atributo que pode ser usado para parametrizar o método _action listener_ correspondente. No Python não sei como faria, na pior das hipóteses dá para subclassear a classe do botão.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A melhor solução, assim como o @Rfroes87 falou na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/527362/157404) dele, é criar um parâmetro com um valor *default* para o `lambda`, que será o valor da variável que você deseja utilizar dentro da função.

Dessa forma, a variável utilizada dentro do `lambda` será tratada como **`local`**, sem a possibilidade de manipulação da mesma em outro escopo.

```
for num in range(100):
    button = Button(root, command = lambda num = num: print(num))
    button.pack()
```

Uma outra solução, que lhe dá um pouco mais de flexibilidade para manipular a criação da função anônima, é criar uma outra função que recebe a função a ser chamada e os argumentos, e depois retorna o `lambda`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
def cria_lambda(func, *args, **kw):
    # Aqui você pode inserir mais código antes de retornar o lambda.
    return lambda: func(*args, **kw)
```

E por fim, temos também uma função própria da linguagem Python, do módulo [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functools.html#module-functools), chamada [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). Essa função faz a mesma coisa que a função acima, com algumas diferenças pequenas em sua implementação.

```
from functools import partial

def func(x): print(x)

f = partial(func, 10)
f() # Imprime o valor 10
```

No caso, a função `partial` não retorna uma função anônima, mas sim um novo objeto de [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects), que possui ainda três atributos (`func`, `args`, `keywords`), como mostra a documentação.

Answer (score 5):

Baseado em uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865170/12195738) no site em inglês, basta você atribuir a função lambda ao valor dinâmico de `i` (durante o *loop* `for...range`) e o mesmo irá persistir quando for executado posteriormente — no caso, ele não irá esperar para executar a função com o valor global de `i` ao final, que seria 99.

Exemplificando com a função `print`, ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

root = Tk()

for i in range(100):
    button = Button(root, command = lambda i=i: print(i))
    button.pack()
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!